# Create multiple button in action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am dynamically adding buttons to my action bar but I don't want to create menu. Each button should be displayed separately same as that in Google Drive Application. 
Someone please help.

Comment: Create custom action bar and add views to it dynamically using code.

Answer (score 1):

Create your custom design for menu button and add that to your action bar.

Code for this:

```
final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();


actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_custom_view_home);

actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
actionBar.setIcon(null);
```